# Django customise project template

Tags: python, django, templates

I am working on writing your first app, part 2 by [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial02/) and is currently stuck in ***Customizing your project’s templates***.

I have copied the *template admin/base_site.html* from the default Django admin template directory into ***mysite/templates/admin***, and make the changes to the base_site.html in the project file.

But there is a **warning message** and **Polls Administration not shown**.

> ?: (1_8.W001) The standalone TEMPLATE_* settings were deprecated in
> Django 1.8 and the TEMPLATES dictionary takes precedence. You must put
> the values of the following settings into your default TEMPLATES dict:
> TEMPLATE_DIRS.

### code for settings.py

TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]

### code for base_site.html

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {{ site_title|default:_('Django site admin') }}{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Polls Administration</a></h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

I have posted on [github repo](https://github.com/cherrythia/djangoapp) for further reference.

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: @e4c5 My apology for missing it out. I have added in. It is because of the warning given and Polls Administration is not shown.

Comment: I wrote the code that raises that deprecation warning. Can you tell me what about it is not clear? It tells you quite plainly that you have put the setting in the wrong place, and where to put it. If you can say what you didn't understand, I'll try and improve it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks for your reply. _default TEMPLATES dict: TEMPLATE_DIRS_ is unclear to me. Probably because of the world TEMPLATE_DIRS. If you put the direct key in the code _DIRS_ might be more accurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be working with Django 1.8 while reading the Django 1.7 tutorial. The 1.8 tutorial is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial02/) The depreciation warning anyway isn't something to worry about. It just seems that your admin template is not in the right place.

When overriding templates the  [Django Debug Toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.3.2/)  is useful to have because it shows exactly what templates are being used. However, it's not essential.